# Codeigniter loading same view on redirect as well

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to redirect to a particular function in a controller while doing login, it works but it loads the same view. my code is below

```
class Authentication extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Authentication_model');
        $this->load->model('Common_model'); 
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) { 
            //If the user is Super Admin
            if ($this->session->userdata('role') == 'Super Admin') {   
                redirect("Admin/adminProfile");
            }elseif ($this->session->userdata('role') == 'Admin') {
                redirect("Outlet/outlets");
            } else {   
                redirect("Authentication/userProfile");
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('authentication/login');
    }
    public function test() {
        die('hi');
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="login-box-body">

                <p class="login-box-msg">Please Login</p> 

                <?php echo form_open(base_url('Authentication/test')); ?>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <?php if (form_error('email_address')) { ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error" style="padding: 5px !important;">
                        <p><?php echo form_error('email_address'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>

                <?php if (form_error('password')) { ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error" style="padding: 5px !important;">
                        <p><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="row"> 
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>


            </div>
```

now when i login it goes to below link

> baseurl.com/Authentication/test

and loads the same login view agian. Please help me whats the issue

Comment: no reason for that to happen unless you have some routes defined. must be something you're not telling us. also no need to wrap base_url around the url in form_open .. does it for you

Comment: if this is the login page then this $this->session->userdata('user_id') always return false n redirects to login page

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line

```
if ($this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
```

with this one

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('user_id')) {
```